# Need to embed a "confirmation link" in an email sent from AS3/PHP

Tags: php, mysql, actionscript-3, email, confirmation

So a component in an app I'm currently developing sends a confirmation email to whoever the user puts in as their "emergency contact" which simply states that the user has chosen them to be the contact.

**What I also want to do, which is what I'm stuck on, is embed a URL in the email that the "emergency contact" would click to confirm that they are fine with being the contact.**

Once clicked, the status "confirmed" in the database would have to change to "true", and from there the app can act differently based on an (if confirmed == true) kind of thing.

Everything is currently built in AS3, with PHP and SQL acting as the backend user database (URLLoader being the connection between AS3 & PHP).

If anyone needs me to be more clear, or give a better example of what I currently have just let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else wondering how to send a confirmation code, check & validate confirmation etc.. this is a really good link that I ended up referencing, which really helped!

**http://pastebin.com/rc89rggc**

Kudos to Irwan who wrote it.

Answer (score 0):

The actual nuts and bolts depends on how you built your server code and how fraud-proof you need your system to be, but in the simplest form the link in your email would be something like:

```
Click <a href="https://mysite.com/confirm?email=[url-encoded contact email goes here]">here</a> to confirm.
```

for the html version of your email. (How you format the email is going to be determined by what libraries you're using to send it, but you will be able to send a message with HTML and non-HTML text that the email client can choose between.)

When clicked this would send a message back to your server with the proper email that you could then mark as confirmed. If you're using a framework, you would probably have a controller named 'confirm', or if not, a file called confirm.php that handles the response.

Note this has no protection whatsoever from fraud; anyone could send that confirmation message. You could add another random field in the link that would be authenticated on the server to improve things a bit, if necessary. Beyond that we're getting into an entirely different discussion.

Comment: Thanks man, defiantly helped me narrow down where to spend my time searching.

Appreciate your time.